# PowerBI participation rate formula with two files

Tags: powerbi

I possess two files - the initial file contains the data for Case ID categorized by team and cluster, while the other file includes information on the actual headcount of sales personnel categorized by team and cluster. I have successfully established a relationship between the two by linking them based on the team name.

My objective is to determine the participation rate of each team. Unfortunately, I am encountering difficulties in obtaining the accurate value.

Table below show the details of the files

File 1 -

Case ID    Team         cluster
1      clementi cbd
2      centre 1 cbd
3      clementi cbd
4      tpy          cbd
5      thiong   cbd
6      thiong   cbd
7      jurong   west
8      jurong   west
9      sun plaza    north east
9      sun plaza    north east
10      paya    east

File 2 -

Actual Headcount    Team    Cluster
9                   clementi    cbd
2               centre 1    cbd
4               tpy         cbd
10              thiong  cbd
7               jurong  west
6               sun plaza   north east
5               paya    east

The output i wish to get is as per below:

cluster   case count    participation rate
cbd        6    24%
clementi      2    22%
centre        1.       50%
tpy           1    25%
thiong        2    20%
west           2    29%
jurong        2    29%
north east    2    33%
sun plaza     2    33%
east           1    20%
paya          1    20%
total         11    26%